# Point of intersection of line and plane in vector form

Tags: vectors, 3d

Find the expression in the vector form for point $\vec{r_1}$ of intersection of plane $\vec{r}.\vec{n}=d$ and the perpendicular line $\vec{r}=\vec{r_0}+t \vec{n}$ where $t$is the parameter.

As $\vec{r_1}$ lies on both line and plane, hence

$\vec{r_1}.\vec{n}=d$

and

$\vec{r_1}=\vec{r_0}+t \vec{n}$
Now in second equation I took dot product with $\vec{n}$ to get

$\vec{r_1} \cdot \vec{n}=\vec{r_0}\cdot \vec{n}+t |\vec{n}|^2$

which gives value of $d$ but how will we separate $\vec{r_1}$ here? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Note that you find the parameter $t$ that gives the coordinates for $\vec{r_1}$.

Comment: In this case, for $t=\dfrac{\vec{r_1} \cdot \vec{n}-\vec{r_0} \cdot \vec{n}}{\vec{n}}$, we have that $$\vec{r_1}=\vec{r_0}+\frac{\vec{r_1} \cdot \vec{n}-\vec{r_0} \cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{n}|^2} \vec{n}$$